# in joomla the images are not displayed in the image slideshow banner

Tags: joomla

i have downloaded a slideshow module for my site.and i have installed it in my site,the module is displayed in the site output but the images are not displayed.I am confused how to display the images in the slideshow.Please help me out.

Comment: Its a good idea to mention what version of Joomla you are using and the slideshow module name.

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to enable the the module under the module manager. Clicking on the slideshow module manager will also reveal the settings for the module, where you can add/remove or change the images.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things to check here, without knowing the exact module you are using:

- Check the module has been enabled and placed on the page you want
- Check the folder or image link is written correctly (e.g. images/IntroSlides displays all the images in that folder for the module I use)
- Check the module width and height is set. This fixed a similar problem for me a few days ago